# Apache NiFi: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Invalid username, password or token) when connecting to Salesforce using JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, salesforce, connection-string, apache-nifi

I began to use RelierSoft JDBC connection driver to connect to Salesforce in NiFi but I cannot connect because of this issue: "**Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Login to "login.salesforce.com" failed: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.)**".

I created connection string based on their documentation and it looks this way:
**jdbc:sforce://login.salesforce.com?user="my_username"&password="my_password"&token="my_token"&api=50.0**

Here is database driver class name:
**com.reliersoft.sforce.jdbc.Driver**

Also when I use the same username, password and security token for CData JDBC driver, everything works fine.
I viewed a lot of Google pages with such error, usually there is a problem with username/password/token. But I am sure that my username, password and security token are correct.
Please let me know what else can be the reason for such issue.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Update: just want to add that there are no special characters neither in password, nor in security token.

Comment: You have quotation marks around your user, password, and token values in your example.  Is that just for illustration, or are you actually using quotation marks in your connection string?  If the quotation marks are included, the driver might be including them in the values.